# Get SVG XML from .svg file via URL using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml, svg

I am trying to get the XML data string from an SVG that is externally hosted. I should note I am using Nodejs. My goal is to embed the contents of my .svg file into a string like below:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">
    <g transform="translate(${x}, ${y}) scale(${scale})">
        //INLINE SVG
    </g>
</svg>`
```

The reason for this approach is so that the svg is inline instead of referenced via a URL. I want to embed the contents of the svg file dynamicallly. The file changes based on an API request so I cannot just open the svg file and copy and paste the contents. It needs to be parsed programmatically so that whatever .svg file is provided via a URL gets turned into inline svg.

What is the best approach to achieve my goal?

Comment: You could also do it Client Side: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an http client, such as [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to get the xml.

This is very straightforward using axios.get:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/SVG_example_markup_grid.svg";

async function downloadSvg(url) {
    let response = await axios.get(url);
    const svgXml = response.data;
    console.log("Svg xml:", svgXml);
}

downloadSvg(url);
```

Once downloaded, the SVG xml will be assigned to the svgXml variable.

Comment: Hey so your solution works really nicely, just wondering how I would go about changing a value that is inside the XML? For example the viewBox value. Is this possible once the svgXml has been received?

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely. I'd suggest using an XML parser for this purpose, something like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js.